# Concate two video with their original Audios using ffmpeg?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I want to concatenate two videos with their original audios. When I run command ffmpeg create video but it remove second video's audio. I use following command to concatenate video with their original audios. How can I do this?

```
applyCommand(new String[]{"-y", "-ss", valuefrom, "-t", valueto, "-i", path1, "-ss", valuefrom2, "-t", valueto2, "-i", path2, "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex", "[0:v]scale=320x240,setsar=1:1[v0];[1:v]scale=320x240,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][v1] concat=n=2:v=1", "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", "320x240", "-r", "15", "-b", "2097k", "-vcodec", "mpeg4", Saving_path});
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the audio for the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat).

Change `[v0][v1] concat=n=2:v=1` to `[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1`.